# Return Nth value from decimal places

Tags: excel, vba, function, decimal

I want to identify certain decimal places on values with vb expression (not with self-created functions). In my vb code the result of the if-query always returns False instead of True in case of example number 10.1349603125

I want that the condition returns True and runs the Then-branch, if

- the third decimal place has the value 4 and
- the fourth decimal place has the value 9 and
- the fifth decimal place has the value greater than 4 and
- the amount (length) of decimal places is greater than 5

The following code returns with the example number 10.1349603125 False (i.e. it runs not the Then-branch) although the condition should return True. Something does not work.

```
....If InStr(3, (Len(.Cells(i, StrVar)) - InStr(1, .Cells(i, StrVar), ".")), "4", vbBinaryCompare) = True And_'// To check if the third decimal place has the value 4
InStr(4, (Len(.Cells(i, StrVar)) - InStr(1, .Cells(i, StrVar), ".")), "9", vbBinaryCompare) = True And_ '// To check if the fourth decimal place has the value 9
InStr(5, (Len(.Cells(i, StrVar)) - InStr(1, .Cells(i, StrVar), ".")), ">4", vbBinaryCompare) = True And_ '// To check if the fifth decimal place has the value greater than 4
(Int(Len(.Cells(i, StrVar))) - Int(InStr(1, .Cells(i, StrVar), ".") > 5)) '// To check if the amount of decimal places is greater than 5
Then....
```

I also tried to invoke the logic of Excel workbook functions into VB code but also this does not work. This code does not work at all:

```
....If (Len(.Cells(i, StrVar).Value) - InStr(1, .Cells(i, StrVar).Value, ".")>4) Then '// To check if the amount of decimal places is greater than 4
If Int(.Cells(i, StrVar) * 10 ^ 3 Mod 10) = 4 And Int(.Cells(i, StrVar) * 10 ^ 4 Mod 10) = 9 And_
Int(.Cells(i, StrVar) * 10 ^ 5 Mod 10) > 4 And (Len(.Cells(i, StrVar).Value) - InStr(1, .Cells(i, StrVar).Value, ".") > 5) Then....
```

Comment: Use math here instead of string functions like `InStr`.

Comment: a) What you mean with "not with self-created functions" ?   ____b) In your code (Sub or Function) use the .Cells(i, StrVar) ten times! It is easier to put it in a string variable...

Comment: Many thanks for your hints. I will check them and will let you know what solves my problem.

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that, when dealing with floating point numbers, some of the maths may not be exact.

For that reason, in the code below, I chose to check the number of decimals used based on the string representation of the number being fed into the function.

Other than that it is simple math.

I also made it a Function rather than an If statement as the logic is easier to follow and modify

```
Option Explicit
Function specs(n As Double) As Boolean
    Dim d3 As Long, d4 As Long, d5 As Long, numDecs As Long
d3 = Right(Int(n * 10 ^ 3), 1)
d4 = Right(Int(n * 10 ^ 4), 1)
d5 = Right(Int(n * 10 ^ 5), 1)

numDecs = Len(Split(Str(n), ".")(1))

specs = d3 = 4 And d4 = 9 And d5 > d3 And numDecs > 5

End Function
```

Comment: Many thanks for you response and help! I will check this and will let you know once I will have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim v, arr, dec, res As Boolean
    
    v = 10.1349603125
    arr = Split(v, ".")
    If UBound(arr) = 1 Then
        dec = arr(1)
        If Len(dec) > 5 Then
            If NumChar(dec, 3) = 4 And _
               NumChar(dec, 4) = 9 And _
               NumChar(dec, 5) > 4 Then
                res = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Debug.Print v, res
End Sub

'return the n'th character from a string as a number
Function NumChar(s, pos As Long) As Long
    NumChar = CLng(Mid(s, pos, 1))
End Function
```

Comment: Many thanks for you response and help @Tim Williams! I will check this and will let you know once I will have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If necessary change the decimalSeparator from "." to "," depending on locale

```
Option Explicit

Public Function isNumberOk(d As Variant) As Boolean
   Dim s As String, p As Integer
   Const decimalSeparator = "."
   
   s = CStr(d)
   p = InStr(1, s, decimalSeparator)
   If p = 0 Then Exit Function
   s = Mid$(s, p + 1)
   If Len(s) <= 5 Then Exit Function
   isNumberOk = (CLng(Mid$(s, 3, 2)) = 49 And CLng(Mid$(s, 5, 1)) > 4)
End Function


Sub tester()
   Dim d As Double
   d = 10.1349603125
   MsgBox (d & "  is " & IIf(isNumberOk(d), "", "NOT") & " Ok")
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for you response and help! I will check this and will let you know once I will have solved the problem.